# Crear un pop-up con dash plotly

Tags: python, python-3.x, aplicación-web, plotly, dash

Tengo un gráfico de barras con etiquetas que aparecen cuando cambiamos de color y me gustaría deshacerme de estas cosas cuando me muevo y crear un Modal cuando hago clic en el gráfico de barras. ¿Sabes cómo puedo manejar eso? Intenté algo pero no aparece nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sabía cómo hacerlo con un datatable. Pero aquí tengo un gráfico de barras, añadí un objeto Modal al final del diseño pero no puedo hacer que aparezca a pesar de...

Aquí está parte de mi código fuente para un ejemplo mínimo reproducible:

```
from os.path import abspath, dirname

import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import spacy
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
# from scoring.bass_scorer.get_attributes import get_perfume, get_perfumes

from server import app

import json

def layout():
    """
    The layout of the attributes webpage
    :return: dash_html_components.Div
    """
    return html.Div([
        # Dropdown with all the required items and a default value.
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='perfume-dropdown',
            options=[{'label': x, 'value': x} for x in data.keys()],
            value='My Burberry - Eau de Parfum'
        ),
        html.Div(id='dd-output-container'),
        # graph of the proportion of attributes in claimed and perceived benefits.
        html.Div([
            dcc.Graph(id='graph-attributes')
        ]),
        dbc.Modal(
            [
                dbc.ModalHeader("Header"),
                dbc.ModalBody("This is the content of the modal"),
                dbc.ModalFooter(
                    dbc.Button("Close", id="close", className="ml-auto")
                ),
            ],
            size="xl",
            id="modal",
        ),
        # calling necessary script for colors
        mathjax_script
    ])


@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='graph-attributes', component_property='figure'),
    [Input(component_id="perfume-dropdown", component_property="value")]
)
def update_graph(my_dropdown):
    """
    Plot the graph of the presence of attributes of product with the name my_dropdown selected in the dropdown.
    :param my_dropdown: the name of the product.
    :return: a figure.
    :rtype: plotly.graph_objs
    """
    data_dropdown = {item: data.get(item)for item in [my_dropdown]} # data.get(my_dropdown, default=None) {item:data.get(item)for item in my_dropdown}
    traces = []
    ticks = []
    colors = []
    d_product = {key: value for (key, value) in data_dropdown[my_dropdown].items()
                 if key not in ['TotalResults', 'Description', 'ReviewTexts']}
    # d_product = sorted(d_product.items(), reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1].get("perceived_benefit", 0.0))
    d_product = {key: value for (key, value) in sorted(d_product.items(), key=lambda e: e[1]["perceived_benefit"])}
    for key, value in d_product.items():
        if key != 'TotalResults':
            trace_claimed = go.Bar(y=[key], x=[value['perceived_benefit']],
                                   name=key + ' Perceived', orientation='h')
            tick = key

            if value['claimed_benefit'] > 0:
                color = 'red'
            else:
                color = 'blue'

            ticks.append(tick)
            colors.append(color)
            traces.append(trace_claimed)

    keys = dict(zip(ticks, colors))
    ticktext = [get_color(v, k) for k, v in keys.items()]

    figure = go.Figure(data=traces,
                       layout=go.Layout(title='Score des parfums sur les attributs',
                                        barmode='stack')
                       )

    figure.update_layout(
        yaxis=dict(tickmode='array', ticktext=ticktext, tickvals=ticks),
        xaxis = dict(
            showgrid=False,
            ticks='',
            showticklabels=False,
        )
    )

    figure.update_layout(
        title="Présence des attributs dans les commentaires du produit",
        xaxis_title="Occurence",
        legend_title="Attributs",
    )

    return figure

def get_comments(word, my_dropdown):
    return [comment for comment in data[my_dropdown]['ReviewTexts'] if word in comment]


@app.callback(Output('modal', 'children'),
              [Input('graph-attributes', 'clickData'),
               Input(component_id="perfume-dropdown", component_property="value")],
              # [State('modal', 'is_open')]
              )
def set_content(clickData, my_dropdown):
    print(clickData)
    word = clickData['points'][0]['y']

    return [
        dbc.ModalHeader(word),
        dbc.ModalBody(
            html.Div([
                html.Div([
                    html.H6('Sales', style={'textAlign': 'center', 'padding': 10}),
                    html.P(get_comments(word, my_dropdown), id="comments", style={'textAlign': 'center', 'padding': 10})
                ], className='pretty_container four columns'),
            ])),
        dbc.ModalFooter(dbc.Button("Close", id="close"))
    ]
```

Pero no aparece ningún modal, ni tampoco ningún error a pesar de crear el callback `set_content()`:

```
@app.callback(Output('modal', 'children'),
              [Input('graph-attributes', 'clickData'),
               Input(component_id="perfume-dropdown", component_property="value")],
              # [State('modal', 'is_open')]
              )
def set_content(clickData, my_dropdown):
    print(clickData)
    word = clickData['points'][0]['y']

    return [
        dbc.ModalHeader(word),
        dbc.ModalBody(
            html.Div([
                html.Div([
                    html.H6('Sales', style={'textAlign': 'center', 'padding': 10}),
                    html.P(get_comments(word, my_dropdown), id="comments", style={'textAlign': 'center', 'padding': 10})
                ], className='pretty_container four columns'),
            ])),
        dbc.ModalFooter(dbc.Button("Close", id="close"))
    ]
```

Aquí hay una pequeña muestra de datos:

```
{
  "My Burberry - Eau de Parfum": {
    "TotalResults": 59,
    "Description": "Inspir\u00e9e du trench coat, de l'h\u00e9ritage stylistique et de la tradition artisanale britanniques, My Burberry capture le parfum d\u2019un jardin londonien apr\u00e8s la pluie. Grand parfum floral r\u00e9v\u00e9lant une signature britannique contemporaine, la fragrance s'\u00e9panouit autour d'un d\u00e9licat c\u0153ur de rose rehauss\u00e9 d\u2019une pointe originale de feuille de g\u00e9ranium. Les notes de t\u00eate compos\u00e9es de pois de senteur et de bergamote se fondent dans un c\u0153ur de g\u00e9ranium, de coing dor\u00e9 et de freesia adoucies par les notes de fond de patchouli et de roses damascena et centifolia rafra\u00eechies par la pluie.",
    "ReviewTexts": [
      "Si vous cherchez qqch floral et pas du tout sucr\u00e9 - voil\u00e0 , MY Burberry est pour vous! Surtout en version EDP ! J'ai achet\u00e9 deja la troisieme pour l'hiver :) uniquement.",
      "J\u2019adore ce parfum, appr\u00e9ci\u00e9 aussi de tout mon entourage, il me fait me sentir f\u00e9minine, \u00e9l\u00e9gante et myst\u00e9rieuse. Il sent toute la journ\u00e9e sans \u00eatre capiteux. Parfait pour les jeunes femmes !",
      "Jai sentie ce parfum il y a quelques ann\u00e9es, d\u00e9j\u00e0. J'adorais son odeur j'ai fini par craqu6er il y a quelques ann\u00e9es et depuis c'est devenu mon top 1. Mon parfum doudou qui me r\u00e9conforte en toute circonstance. Un must have \u00e0 avoir dans sa salle de bain.",
      "My Burberry  tient longtemps et l'odeur est tout simplement sublime! Sensuel, doux et glamour mais tr\u00e8s frais \u00e0 la fois. mettez ce parfum et vous serez combl\u00e9es. Ce parfum tient toute la journ\u00e9e"
    ],
    "je me sens bien": {
      "claimed_benefit": 0,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.0
    },
    "romantique": {
      "claimed_benefit": 0,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.0
    },
    "me convient bien": {
      "claimed_benefit": 0,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.01694915254237288
    },
    "f\u00e9minin": {
      "claimed_benefit": 0,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.03389830508474576
    },
    "sensuel / sexy": {
      "claimed_benefit": 0,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.0
    },
    "nettoyer": {
      "claimed_benefit": 0,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.0
    },
    "facile a porter": {
      "claimed_benefit": 0,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.22033898305084745
    },
    "haute qualite": {
      "claimed_benefit": 0,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.0
    },
    "elegante / sophistiquee": {
      "claimed_benefit": 0,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.0
    },
    "jeune / juvenile": {
      "claimed_benefit": 0,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.15254237288135594
    },
    "moderne": {
      "claimed_benefit": 1,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.11864406779661017
    },
    "sucr\u00e9": {
      "claimed_benefit": 0,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.0847457627118644
    },
    "naturel": {
      "claimed_benefit": 1,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.13559322033898305
    },
    "pour le soir / nuit": {
      "claimed_benefit": 0,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.288135593220339
    },
    "frais": {
      "claimed_benefit": 1,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.288135593220339
    },
    "doux": {
      "claimed_benefit": 0,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.423728813559322
    },
    "lumi\u00e8re": {
      "claimed_benefit": 0,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.2542372881355932
    },
    "classique": {
      "claimed_benefit": 0,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.0
    },
    "chaud": {
      "claimed_benefit": 0,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.11864406779661017
    },
    "audacieux": {
      "claimed_benefit": 0,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.0
    },
    "humide": {
      "claimed_benefit": 0,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.0
    },
    "poudreux": {
      "claimed_benefit": 0,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.0
    },
    "herbes aromatiques": {
      "claimed_benefit": 0,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.0
    },
    "a du caractere": {
      "claimed_benefit": 1,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.1864406779661017
    },
    "sportif": {
      "claimed_benefit": 0,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.0
    },
    "aquatique / marine": {
      "claimed_benefit": 0,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.0
    },
    "floral": {
      "claimed_benefit": 1,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.03389830508474576
    },
    "nouveau / jamais respire avant": {
      "claimed_benefit": 1,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.15254237288135594
    },
    "savonneux": {
      "claimed_benefit": 0,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.0
    },
    "pour la journee": {
      "claimed_benefit": 0,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.0
    },
    "n'oublier": {
      "claimed_benefit": 0,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.0
    },
    "vanille": {
      "claimed_benefit": 0,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.0
    },
    "fruit\u00e9": {
      "claimed_benefit": 0,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.0
    },
    "masculin": {
      "claimed_benefit": 0,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.0
    },
    "citronn\u00e9": {
      "claimed_benefit": 0,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.01694915254237288
    },
    "enfum\u00e9": {
      "claimed_benefit": 0,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.0
    },
    "vert / herbe-like": {
      "claimed_benefit": 1,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.06779661016949153
    },
    "oriental": {
      "claimed_benefit": 0,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.0
    },
    "\u00e9pic\u00e9": {
      "claimed_benefit": 0,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.0
    },
    "alimentaire": {
      "claimed_benefit": 0,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.0
    },
    "bois\u00e9": {
      "claimed_benefit": 0,
      "perceived_benefit": 0.0
    }
  }
}
```